# In a four hand draw without replacement, what is the probability that no subsequent ranks are the same?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

As an example, $J,K,3,K$, or $K,3,4,K$, or $K,J,A,2$ are allowed, but not $K,K,J,3$ or $4,10,K,K$.

I was thinking that maybe I could approach this question by counting the number of ways such that a rank does occur twice in a row, divide this by $\frac{52!}{48!}$ and subtract the result by 1 but I am unsure.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first card we draw does not depend on any previous draw, so we just assign it a $\frac{52}{52}$ probability. The second draw cannot be the same rank as the previous, and we still have $51-3=48$ cards left in the deck that do not have the previous rank, so we assign our second draw a $\frac{48}{51}$ probability.

Now the difficult part:

Suppose our first three draws were $K,Q,K$ (for example). The probability of getting the same card on our third draw as we did on our first draw is $\frac{3}{50}$. Now, for the fourth draw, there are only $49-2=47$ cards left in the deck that are not Kings, so we assign our fourth draw to be $\frac{47}{49}$.

Now suppose our first three draws were $K,Q,J$ (for example). The probability of not getting the same card on our third draw as we did on our first is $\frac{44}{50}$ (since there are still $50-3-3=44$ cards left in the deck that are not Queens or Kings). For the final draw, there are $49-3=46$ cards still left in our deck that are not Jacks, so we assign this probability to be $\frac{46}{49}$.

If we combine these two cases in general, then our ultimate probaility becomes:

$\frac{52}{52}\cdot \frac{48}{51}\cdot \frac{3}{50}\cdot\frac{47}{49}+\frac{52}{52}\cdot \frac{48}{51}\cdot \frac{44}{50}\cdot\frac{46}{49}=\frac{3464}{4165}\approx83.17\%$

Comment: Makes so much sense, thank you for the explanation! :) I do have one question though, if you don't mind since I'm a bit of a noob, would a sequence like $K,Q,Q,K$ still mean the same as the first example you've given? So the probability for that sequence would be $\frac{52}{52}$ $\cdot$ $\frac{48}{51}$ $\cdot$ $\frac{47}{50}$ $\cdot$ $\frac{3}{49}$ which is essentially the same as your first example just transposed but would I need to add this instance to the overall probability as well?

Comment: Well we don't want to include the case when the second and third ranks are the same because the probability we want to calculate assumes that no two identical ranks can be drawn one after the other. Think of it this way, the first card can be anything it wants, say $A$. The second card can't be $A$, so let's call it $B$. Now our sequence so far is $A,B$. But, the third card is allowed to be $A$ again, so we're left with two cases: $A,B,A$ or $A,B,C$.

Comment: Oops sorry, my bad. I meant to say $K,Q,J,K$. But I understand now, thanks. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Just to clarify, $K,Q,J,K$ still fits into our second case above because, for the fourth draw, we only require that it can't be a Jack, and there are $49-3=46$ cards left in the deck that are not Jacks. Within those $46$ cards are still $3$ Kings, so drawing the $K$ as our last card does not affect our overall calculation.

Comment: Please check my answer again as I have made a correction in the second step.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a direct calculation conditioning on whether the third card matches the first.  What is the chance the second card does not match the first?  What is the chance the third card matches neither?  In that case, what is the chance the fourth does not match the third?  What is the chance the third card matches the first (and therefore does not match the second)?  In that case, what is the chance the fourth does not match the third?